# Is there a way to install gym-retro with Anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, openai-gym

I know it is possible to get the gym library using Anaconda but I did not find anything about the gym-retro one.
Does anyone know how to get this?

Comment: Use the search feature on the anaconda website [to see that there is no version in any channel](https://anaconda.org/search?q=gym-retro)

Comment: that said, you can use pip to install it in one of your conda environments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.